# Create generic array from type specific arrays in Clojure

Tags: arrays, clojure, jfreechart

I am  working with JFreeChart in clojure and came across a situation I'd like help.

JFreeChart's DefaultXYDataset has a method addSeries which is used to add series to the chart. The data is supposed to be an array containing [two arrays](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/data/xy/DefaultXYDataset.html#addSeries-java.lang.Comparable-double:A:A-) which are type specific(Array of doubles). I therefore wrote the following code thinking it would work but i get a 
`ClassCastException` that `class [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to class [[D ([Ljava.lang.Object; and [[D are in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')`.

```clj
(doto _dataset
  (.addSeries "S1" (to-array (conj
                               []
                               (double-array (range 10))
                               (double-array (range 10))))))
```

After looking through i realized that `to-array` converts the two nested arrays to `#object["[Ljava.lang.Object;" 0x491223e7 "[Ljava.lang.Object;@491223e7"]` instead of the intended `#object["[D" 0x4f5cf37 "[D@4f5cf37"] #object["[D" 0x6d895193 "[D@6d895193"]`. Is there a way of combining them to a generic array without converting them to arrays of longs? Maybe another method apart from `to-array`. Any other suggestions are welcome. Thanks.

Edit: @bfabry answer will work, i could use `make-array` and then use `aset-double` but this will result in me looping through the two sequences and assign their values to the main array. I am trying to avoid this as the two datasets can be quite big, even up to [300k items](https://github.com/incanter/incanter/issues/64) each.

Comment: Also consider extending `AbstractXYDataset`, as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=user%3a230513%20%5bjfreechart%5d%20extends%20AbstractXYDataset).

Comment: Thanks for the link @trashgod . I will check it out. Currently i am trying to use DefaultXYDataset to fix [this issue](https://github.com/incanter/incanter/issues/64) though.

Comment: Also consider `FastScatterPlot`, suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=user%3a230513%20%5bjfreechart%5d%20FastScatterPlot).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's two dimensional array, not an array of two array objects. You'll need to use `make-array` and `aset-double` to make the array you want.

```
user=> (class (make-array Double/TYPE 2 2))
[[D
```

https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/make-array

Comment: Your answer is correct, but i was trying to avoid this because using ```aset-double``` will result in me looping through all the items in the two collections and assign them to the array individually. The datasets i am working with can be quite big, even 300k. I don't think looping through them would be a good idea.

Comment: Your original proposed method is copying all of the data, too, so except for constant factors in the looping method, is not going to be faster than linear time in the number of data elements you want to send to JFreeChart.

Comment: Extending `AbstractXYDataset` may help minimize copying.

Comment: @andy_fingerhut I get what you are saying, Thank you. I would like to ask if using ```cons``` instead  of ```conj``` would make it any faster. I suppose that lazying would work make it faster.

Comment: I do not know off the top of my head whether `cons` vs. `conj` would make any noticeable performance difference.  Experimentation and measurement could answer that.  At most it would change the constant factors involved, not linear time vs. non-linear time.  Constant factors do matter sometimes, I know.

Comment: I can't be bothered measuring it, but a loop setting each of the elements of a single primitive java array is probably going to be about as fast as anything can be.